# BeautifulSoup: Order of seemingly independent replacements changes outcome. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

REPLACEMENTS = [('u', '<span class="underline">{}</span>'),
                ('b', '<strong>{}</strong>'),
                ('i', '<em>{}</em>')]

def replace_tags(html, replacements=REPLACEMENTS):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for tag, template in replacements:
        for node in soup.find_all(tag):
            replacement = template.format(node.text)
            r = BeautifulSoup(replacement, 'html.parser')
            node.replace_with(r)
    return str(soup)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_html = """<html><body><p><b>I am strong</b> and 
    <i>I am emphasized</i> and <u>I am underlined</u>.</p></body></html>"""

    revised = replace_tags(my_html, REPLACEMENTS)
    print(revised)
```

This does not replace `<i>` tags.

```
<html><body><p><strong>I am strong</strong> and 
<i>I am emphasized</i> and <span class="underline">I am underlined</span>.</p></body></html>
```

But if I change the order of the tuples within `REPLACEMENTS` to

```
REPLACEMENTS = [('b', '<strong>{}</strong>'),
                ('i', '<em>{}</em>'),
                ('u', '<span class="underline">{}</span>')]
```

Then `<i>` and `<u>` tags are not replaced:

```
<html><body><p><strong>I am strong</strong> and 
<i>I am emphasized</i> and <u>I am underlined</u>.</p></body></html>
```

Reordering again...

```
REPLACEMENTS = [('i', '<em>{}</em>'),
                ('b', '<strong>{}</strong>'),
                ('u', '<span class="underline">{}</span>')]
```

now the output is

```
<html><body><p><strong>I am strong</strong> and 
<em>I am emphasized</em> and <u>I am underlined</u>.</p></body></html>
```

The `<u>` replacement isn't made.

I cannot for figure out why the order has this effect on the output. These aren't nested. Each pass seems to make an independent replacement. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Can I just check my_html has em not i tags?

Comment: @Dan-Dev Correct. <b> and <i> are replaced with <strong> and <em> respectively, regardless of order. <u> is only replaced with the <span> if it is the specified in first replacement tuple within `REPLACEMENTS`. Odd, huh?

Comment: in your code my_html has em tags not i tags so in your example i is not being replaced but the answer is that replace_with() replaces with a string not a NavigableString full answer to follow shortly

Comment: Good catch. Revising question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was why does this happen and the answer to the question is that you are replacing using replace_with() and providing a string. A string is not a navigablestring see 
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring
So you can no longer navigate with BeautifulSoup on the part you replaced. If you replace with a new tag they are navigatabe so the following works in all cases.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def replace_tags(html, replacements):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for tag in replacements:
        for node in soup.find_all(tag):
            if tag == 'i':
                newtag = soup.new_tag("em")
            if tag == 'b':
                newtag = soup.new_tag("strong")
            if tag == 'u':
                newtag = soup.new_tag("span", **{'class':'underline'})
            newtag.string = node.string
            node.replace_with(newtag)
    return str(soup)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_html = """<html><body><p><b>I am strong</b> <b>I am strong too</b> and 
    <i>I am emphasized</i> and <u>I am underlined</u>.</p></body></html>"""
    replacements = ['i','b','u']
    revised = replace_tags(my_html, replacements)
    print(revised)
    replacements = ['b','u','i']
    revised = replace_tags(my_html, replacements)
    print(revised)
    replacements = ['u','i','b']
    revised = replace_tags(my_html, replacements)
    print(revised)
```

**UPDATED**
I overlooked the line:

```
r = BeautifulSoup(replacement, 'html.parser')
```

but I don't think you can add a tag from another soup and navigate it for the same reason. All the documentation I have read involves creating a new tag from the original soup and using that.

Comment: Ah. I thought that by "soupifying" the replacement, e.g., with `r = BeautifulSoup(replacement, 'html.parser')` that it would preserve the navigable property. Thanks!

Comment: Oops I didn't see that line but I don't think you can add a tag from another soup and navigate it for the same reason. All the documentation I have read involves creating a new tag from the original soup and using that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You are correct, and your solution works like a charm!